# Returning type of triangle, does not recognize identifier

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that, when given three `int` values that represent triangle side lengths, will tell me what kind of triangle I have. Here is the code:

```
public String printTriangleType(int a, int b, int c) {
   if (a == b && b == c) 
      return equilateral;
   else if (a == b && b != c && a != c) 
      return isosceles;
   else if (a == c && b != c && b != a) 
      return isosceles;
   else if (b == c && c != b && c != a) 
      return isosceles;
   else
      return scalene;
}
```

The program that is checking my code is telling me that it does not recognize the identifiers `equilateral`, `isosceles`, and `scalene`. Why is that?

Comment: Put your `String` literals in quotes, e.g. `"equilateral"`.

Comment: `else return "scalene";`.

Comment: You could also define constants with names, e.g. `public static final String EQUILATERAL = "equilateral";` and then `return EQUILATERAL;` If you do this, the convention is to use upper-case for the identifier.  The advantage is that you only have to type in each string once, and you don't have to worry about a typo in your string causing the program to stop working.

Comment: An `enum` would be even better, but you probably haven't learned about them yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` literals in Java are denoted by quotes (`"`). Without them, Java attempts to interprets them as variable names and fails, as you did not define such variables:

```
public String printTriangleType(int a, int b, int c) {
   if (a == b && b == c) 
      return "equilateral";
   else if (a == b && b != c && a != c) 
      return "isosceles";
   else if (a == c && b != c && b != a) 
      return "isosceles";
   else if (b == c && c != b && c != a) 
      return "isosceles";
   else
      return "scalene";
}
```

Comment: I added the quotes. The software then tells me that it expected a return type: void.

Comment: @rpeck3 On what line are you getting this error? This method compiles perfectly for me.

Comment: I am using a website to test this code, so it automatically compiles and runs it. Usually it gives me a line that it hit an error at, but for this particular problem it simply says "Return types do not match. expected return type: void. your return type was: String" Is there a way I could do this using    public void printTriangleType    ?

Comment: If it's `void` you won't be able to return a value... Are you sure you're pasting the code properly? Also, why not just use the proper compiler in your JDK?

Comment: That is why I am confused. My school is incapable of getting Dr. Java or a similar program on the computers.